# Nsubstitute is there a away to check parameter value of void method

Tags: nsubstitute

Hi i am struggling with a unit test scenario using Nsubstitute i have substituted my data class and i am testing that my controller is passing in the correct parameter for the save process.
my code is as follows

```
  int counter = 0;
    int callCounter = 0;

    IClubData clubData;
    IClubDTO club = new ClubDTO { ID = 2, ClubName = "Test 2" };
    IClubDTO dclub = new ClubDTO { ID = 1, ClubName = "Test 1" };

    [SetUp]
    public void Intilise()
    {
        clubData = Substitute.For<IClubData>();

        clubData.Clubs.Returns(data.mockClubsDTO);
        
        var dataitems = new ClubDataItems();

        dataitems.Clubs.Add((ClubDTO)club);
        dataitems.DeletedClubs.Add((ClubDTO)dclub);

        clubData.When(x => x.ProccessClubs(dataitems)).Do(x => counter++);
        clubData.When(x => x.ProccessClubs(Arg.Any<IClubDataItems>())).Do(x => callCounter++);
    }

 [Test]
    public void SaveChanges_CorrectParameters()
    {
       List<ClubDTO> clubs = new List<ClubDTO>();
        clubs.Add((ClubDTO)club);

        List<ClubDTO> dclubs = new List<ClubDTO>();
        dclubs.Add((ClubDTO)dclub);

        var httpContext = Substitute.For<HttpContext>();
        var mockSession = new MockHttpSession();

        mockSession.Set("clubs", clubs);
        mockSession.Set("deletedclubs", dclubs);

        httpContext.Session = mockSession;

        var clubController = new ClubController(clubData)
        {
            ControllerContext = new ControllerContext { HttpContext = httpContext }
        };

        clubController.SaveChanges();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, callCounter);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, counter);

    }
```

when I run the test the call counter gets incremented so i believe the method is being called but with not with the expected parameters. Is there a way for me to extract the parameter within in the test itself as when i debug the test and step through the savechanges method it would appear it should be returning the correct value.
The savechanges code is

```
public void SaveChanges()
    {
        var dataItems = new ClubDataItems();

        dataItems.Clubs = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ClubDTO>>("clubs");
        dataItems.DeletedClubs = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ClubDTO>>("deletedclubs");

        _clubData.ProccessClubs(dataItems);
    }
```

I have tried to use `clubData.Received().ProccessClubs(Arg.Do<IClubDataItems>(p => testItems = p));` however testitems is being set to null.

Any hints on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I thinkg `clubData.When(x => x.ProccessClubs(dataitems)).Do(x => counter++)` is being over-written by `clubData.When(x => x.ProccessClubs(Arg.Any<IClubDataItems>())).Do(x => callCounter++)`. You can't use `Received` with `Arg.Do`, so when you are stubbing your calls you can try `clubData.ProcessClubs(Arg.Do<IClubDataItems>(p => testItems = p))`.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging some more the solution was to put the following code when i set up the method call.

```
clubData.When(x => x.ProccessClubs(Arg.Any<IClubDataItems>())).Do(x => testItems=x.Arg<IClubDataItems>());
```

This then assigns the parameters returned to that method i am then doing asserts on the 2 list items to ensure they contain the items i was expecting.

Still not sure why the following wasn't working as anticipated.

```
clubData.When(x => x.ProccessClubs(dataitems)).Do(x => counter++);
```